# run php script at regular intervals and record count

Tags: php, csv

I think i was not clear earlier. this is what I am trying to do.

I have 1000 records in a csv file, i am parsing it using php fgetcsv. Now I can get the record count and the data. Now i need to have a loop such that iterate through first 100 records, sleep/pause for 2 minutes, then continue from 101-200, 201-300 and so on until 901-1000. then it stops. Please let me know if it's clear.

regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there's no time-between-requests limit on the API, there's no need for cron or whatnot, simply keep a count of how many rows have been processed and then hit the API after every 100 rows.

if there is a time limit, then you could have the script `sleep()` until the limit is up and then continue on in the loop:

```
$i = 0;

while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) { // assuming you've already opened the file;
     ... do some processing ...
     $i++; // increment counter
     if ($i % 100 == 0) { 
          ... done 100 records, send to API
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is kind pseudocode in php style (adapt it to your api)

```
$i = 0, $j = 0;  
while(1) {  
 if($j > 100) {  
    Send(AccumulationBuffer);
    flush(AccumulationBuffer); 
    $j = 0;
    sleep($myInterval);  
 }  
if($i == EndOfFile)  
    break;  

 AccumulationBuffer.add($i);  
 $i++;  
 $j++;  
}
```

Comment: not sure if i wasn't clear. this is what i need. have 1000 records in a csv file, i am parsing it using php, now have the record count and the records. Now i need to have a loop such that iterate through 100 records, sleep/pause for 2minutes, then continue from 101-200, 201-300 and so on until 901-1000. then it stops. Please let me know if it's clear..we can ignore the API.

Comment: what is AccumulationBuffer ? is it a constant that you want me to assign? can you please more specific if this is marked as answer?

Comment: @Jay (For second) It's the data structure where you are storing (accumulating) the records which are to be sent; can be an array, stack, list or anything relevant. It is a general term I have used. Keep on adding CSV records to the AccumulationBuffer until you reach hundred, then send that data structure and empty (`flush(AccumulationBuffer)`) it before you begin your next cycle.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count =1;
foreach ($csv->data as $key => $row){   
     foreach ($row as $value) {       
         $output =  "$value"; 
        echo $output;
        $count++;
        if(($count % 100) == 0){
        echo "Sleep for 5 minutes"."\n"; //will sleep after 100 records.
        sleep(300);
        }
     }
}
```

please correct me if there is anything wrong..

Answer (score -1):

Add a shebang to your php file and put the full paths of your php and csv files in the crontab. E.g:

1 * * * * /path/to/dir/myscript.php

then have your 'csv counter' in another file that you open, read, increment and write on each iteration